# Is it possible to cast ElementRef to NgControl?

Tags: validation, angular

I'm trying to create custom validator as `@Directive`, and the problem is that in constructor I can access only `ElementRef object`, however i need some methods from `NgControl`.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[my-directive][ngModel]",
  providers: [some providers here]
})
export class MyValidator extends RootValidator {


  constructor(el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
    super(el, renderer);
    // TODO: Here i need access to ngControl instead of ElementRef
    errorsFromServerEmitter.subscribe(next => {
        // ... some useful code here and then
        ngControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    })
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    // ... some validations
    return errors;
  }
```

I need to react on responses from server somehow. In this responses I get "`extended`" errors which know about DB consistency and some other stuff...